# Threejs Orbit Control: is it possible to have continuous vertical rotation?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have a simple scene where no new object is added after the initial setup. To enable camera rotation, I've used orbit control which works great except that the vertical rotation is not continuous (in the OrbitControls.js it's set to the maximum possible value which is `Math.Pi`; code [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js)). Is there a way to get around this limit?

I'm thinking to manually set the reference position and orientation of the orbit controls to the current values for the camera after each `change` event and then reset the control using `controls.reset()`, although I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Trackball control does rotate the camera the way I want, but I have to use `requestAnimationFrame` shim for it which is overkill for my purpose and puts too much (unnecessary) pressure on the CPU.

Comment: it might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961397/three-js-rotation-over-its-own-axis

Comment: I expect your efforts would be best spent figuring how to modify `TrackballControls` so `requestAnimationFrame` is not required.

Comment: Thanks JAre, it was useful. WestLangley, that was indeed the way to go. I ended up adding `this._update()` to the mouse events in `TrackballControls` and now it works without the animation shim. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: could you provide the code by any chance user31208 ? I'm stuck with this same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Timothy here you go [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/41de45bb7eccb0477163)